# 3D reconstruction with only stereo pair of images and no calibrated camera

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, matlab-cvst, stereoscopy

I have two spatial images but I have no camera calibration input. How can I develop a 3D model by just reading both the images using *imread*? 
Also I tried to follow this code but this needs camera parameters too.

http://in.mathworks.com/discovery/stereo-vision.html

I also tried to come up with a 3D sparse modelling but it doesn't work.

http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-two-views.html

Can I use Gaussian filters or something like that to input image data from the stereo pairs and then match them for dept estimation. If i get the depth I can make the 3D model.

Please suggest what can be done fast I am running out of time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't say exactly what you need in terms of 3D model. Do you need a Euclidean model  (i.e. to know the lengths of all sides? ) or is it to scale only (metric reconstruction)?

Secondly what do you know about the images ? Were they taken from the same camera at different time points ? Different cameras ? How were the cameras arranged ? There are special cases that may make 3D recovery easier however in the general case you will not be able to get a metric reconstruction without camera calibration.

Having said that you could try reading [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.16.946&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on calibration from vanishing points or [this one](http://www.dip.ee.uct.ac.za/publications/theses/MScArne.pdf)

It's possible, if you know the type of cameras, that someone has got calibration parameters that would be good enough - defending on the quality of the cameras.

The geometry behind this is not trivial and we need to know more before recommending a solution.

Comment: Ok so i have this project where I have to take fractography data. We use Scanning Electron Microscope(SEM) to study the fracture surface and generate images using an image scanning software. I have two views of the same surface. One taken at +4 degree rotation and one at -4 degree. I have been asked to generate a 3D model of the fracture surface using these.

Comment: I don't think I can get any calibration data from the SEM labs.  So yes both my images were taken from the same camera and the inclined images were taken only by tilting the position of the specimen plate. I need a metric reconstruction definitely. Could you tell me what kind of cases are easy to recover in 3D i might try to arrange my images like that.

Comment: If you have two cameras which have optical axes that are absolutely parallel (or in your case, if you displace the subject laterally, then you won't need to recover epipolar geometry and rectify images so you can skip directly to generating a disparity map from the images. The problem is that even with this data you cannot accurately reconstruct the 3D model without deriving the intrinsic camera parameters. I have no idea what these would look like for a SEM (or even if the pinhole assumption would hold in the first place!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that without any calibration at all, all you can get is a reconstruction up to an unknown projective transformation. That means you will not get the absolute sizes of objects, and you angles will be wrong. The best thing to do is to calibrate your cameras.

If you cannot do that, you can get part of the way there using the `estimateUncalibratedRectification` and `disparity` functions. See this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/uncalibrated-stereo-image-rectification.html). Once you have the disparity, you are going to have to make up fake camera parameters like the focal length, the optical center, and the distance between the cameras, and write your own code to do the reconstruction. Again, it will be an up-to-projective reconstruction. See "Learning OpenCV" by Bradsky and Kaehler.